# Is it possible to commit in TortoiseGit with --no-verify flag?

Tags: windows, git, commit, tortoisegit, pre-commit-hook

I installed a git precommit hook and sometimes I want to commit with `--no-verify` flag. I know how to do that in command line but I'd like to do that in TortoiseGit (since command line is very poor in Windows). How can I do that? I read through https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-commit.html but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Update: with TortoiseGit 2.13.1 it started to totally ignore `.git/hooks` hooks.
At the same time they added TortoiseGit internal hooks that can be created manually in the settings. And if that hooks fail, TortoiseGit provides selection to cancel commit, or ignore that fail.

The problem for me was to run bash-script based hook under Windows where there is no bash. I failed to make it and downgraded TortoiseGit back to v2.12.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible right now (as of 2.13.0.0) - it's not documented explicitly, just deducible using the source code.

If you use TortoiseGit, you should consider to use [TortoiseGit hooks](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks) instead of vanilla git hooks.

Comment: Added a note about TortoiseGit's own hooks.